# Are all Coxeter groups virtually free or virtually surface groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, coxeter-groups, free-groups

From *Surface subgroups of Coxeter and Artin groups* (Gordon, Long and Reid, 2003) [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2003.10.011), we can read that (Theorem 1.1) a Coxeter group is either virtually free or contains a surface group ($\pi_1$ of a closed orientable surface of genus $\ge 1$).

My question is:
Are all Coxeter groups virtually free or virtually surface groups?

Comment: There are Coxeter groups that contain free abelian groups (of any fixed rank). So, no?

Comment: Yes/No [you're asking a question and then its negative...]: if it contains a direct product of a free group with $\mathbf{Z}$ then it can't be virtually free/surface. It's quite immediate to produce such examples. But even among Gromov-hyperbolic Coxeter groups, many are not virtually surface/free (e.g., have virtual cohomological dimension $\ge 2$)

Comment: Also, please don’t ask a question *and* it’s negation in the same paragraph… it is very confusing.  Thank you!

Comment: By the way most affine Coxeter groups are counterexamples to the quoted assertion, you probably omit some assumption which most likely was written by the quoted authors.

Comment: @YCor The statement in the paper is "a hyperbolic Coxeter group is virtually free or contains a hyperbolic surface group", and a Coxeter group is hyperbolic if and only if it does not contain $\mathbf{Z}^2$, so OP's statement seems correct to me (note that OP does not write "contains a hyperbolic surface group").

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I've added the missing convention, which is indeed explicit in the linked paper and is needed to make things meaningful.

Comment: A free product between a virtually free group and virtually a surface group also gives an easy counterexample.

Comment: By the way "hyperbolic Coxeter group" has widely been used (including before Gromov-hyperbolicity was coined) in a more restrictive sense — for instance it excludes a free product $Z/2Z$ with a virtual (hyperbolic closed surface group), which is Gromov-hyperbolic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When asking a question about Coxeter groups, it might be useful to focus on right-angled Coxeter groups first: usually, they are easier to handle. Below are a few criteria you can play with in order to create various examples of (right-angled) Coxeter groups.

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite simplicial graph. The right-angled Coxeter group $C(\Gamma)$ is:

- finite if and only if $\Gamma$ is complete;
- virtually free if and only if $\Gamma$ is chordal (i.e. it does not contain an induced cycle of length $\geq 4$);
- virtually abelian of rank $n \geq 1$ if and only if $\Gamma$ decomposes as a join of a complete graph and $n$ copies of $K_2^{\mathrm{opp}}$ (= two isolated vertices);
- virtually a hyperbolic surface group if and only if $\Gamma$ decomposes as a join of a complete graph and a cycle of length $\geq 5$;
- hyperbolic if and only if $\Gamma$ is square-free (i.e. it does not contain an induced cycle of length $4$);
- a free product if and only if $\Gamma$ is disconnected;
- multi-ended if and only if $\Gamma$ contains a separating complete subgraph (possibly empty).